# How to solve "syncfusion_flutter_pdf: removeAt(0) null check" error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf, mobile

```dart
//Loads an existing PDF document

PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.pdf').readAsBytesSync());

//Gets the second page of the document

PdfPage page = document.pages[1];

//Removes the second page from the document

document.pages.remove(page);

//Removes the first page from the document

document.pages.removeAt(0);

//Saves the document

File('output.pdf').writeAsBytes(await document.save());

//Disposes the document

document.dispose();
```

The above outputs:

> null check error syncfusion_flutter_pdf:

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.